# Converting a panda dataframe into vectors

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a panda dataframe consisting of 3 column (x, y and z). I am looking to convert the entire dataframe into vectors (by row). I have tried by converting it to numpy and also use lambda, but I can't seem to find out an ideal way. I need to do some manipulation of each vector later on, so what is the best course of action?

```
data = [[7.68, -0.3, -98.55],[7.59, 1.20, -99.26],[7.69, -0.2, -97.23],[6.98, 1.32, -98.98]]


AATOMS = []
for x in ATOMS:
    AATOMS.append(x.split())


atomdata = pd.DataFrame(AATOMS,columns = ['x','y','z'])
atomdata['x'] = atomdata['x'].astype(float)
atomdata['y'] = atomdata['y'].astype(float)
atomdata['z'] = atomdata['z'].astype(float)

#df = atomdata.assign(p = lambda y:?
```

I'm not too sure what the ideal output data would be. Because if the output data is just a list of the rows (xyz, xyz, xyz...) would I be able to operate on it? Maybe I am confusing myself

My end goal is to covert the cartesian coordinates of each vector to spherical coordinates, rotate every vector by some theta value, and then convert back to cartesian. I decided that it would be better to get the array somehow into individual vectors this would be easiest.

Comment: What do you mean by "vectors"? Numpy arrays of dimension 1?

Comment: I meant vector as in a single component just consisting of x, y, z. So yes that would be an array of dimension 1.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result.

Comment: my code creates an empty dataframe and then reads the data from a file, but I will provide some example data for a few rows

Comment: Good. Please also indicate the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the columns of a DataFrame into a dict of `{column_name: vector_values}`, a simple way is:

```py
# we don't know what the original data is, making up an init
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(3*4).reshape(-1, 3), columns=list('xyz'))

# then
vectors = {k: ser.values for k, ser in df.iteritems()}

>>> vectors
{'x': array([0, 3, 6, 9]),
 'y': array([ 1,  4,  7, 10]),
 'z': array([ 2,  5,  8, 11])}
```

But your question needs clarification. I'm not sure what result you are actually seeking.